# Get the height of a particular datepicker instance?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Just want to get the height of the datepicker once it has been generated:

```
$(function(){

            $("#MyDatePicker").datepicker(
                // Options
                {
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                numberOfMonths: 1,

                onSelect:function(selectedDate){
                    alert(**My_Datepicker_Instance_Height????**);

                }


            });

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the outerHeight (padding included) of the current visible datepicker:

```
$(".ui-datepicker:visible").outerHeight();
```

Comment: Great job buddy : ) I'll buy you a beer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/)**:

```
$(function () {
    $("#MyDatePicker").datepicker(
        // Options
        {
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
                alert($(this).height());
            }

        });

});
```

Comment: I must be somewhat confused - I tried this method before and the one above as well.. I got back 19 - yet the calender box that displays is at least 250px - is it returning the font size or something?

Comment: Please go to jsfiddle.net and try to make a demo for us to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [this](https://api.jquery.com/height/#height2).

```
alert( $( '#MyDatePicker' ).height() );
```

Comment: I must be somewhat confused - I tried this method before and the one bellow as well.. I got back 19 - yet the calender box that displays is at least 250px - is it returning the font size or something?